# PHP field dropdown values from 08-17 instead of 00-17

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have zero knowledge in php and would really appreciate your help. I have this code where I want the drop down field to show values from 08 to 17 (so: 08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17). Now is displaying from 00 to 17. Can somebody help me fix this?

This is the code:

```
// hours
    $string .= '        <option value=""></option>' . "\n";
    $tf_hours = (self::$form_options['time_format'] == '24') ? '17' : '12';
    for ( $keyi = (self::$form_options['time_format'] == '24') ? 0 : 1; $keyi <= $tf_hours; $keyi++ ) {
        $keyi = sprintf( "%02d", $keyi );
        if ( self::$form_content[$field['slug']]['h'] != '' ) {
            if ( self::$form_content[$field['slug']]['h'] == "$keyi" ) {
                $selected = ' selected="selected"';
            }
        }
        $string .= '        <option value="' . esc_attr( $keyi ) . '"' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( $keyi ) . '</option>' . "\n";
        $selected = '';
    }
    $string .= "      </select>:\n      <select ";
    $string .= ($field['input_css'] != '') ? self::convert_css( $field['input_css'] ) : self::get_this_css('select_style');
    $string .= ' id="fscf_field' . self::$form_id_num . '_' . $key . 'm" name="' . $field['slug'] . '[m]">' . "\n";
    $selected = '';
```

Comment: hmmm you might want to consider using a templating library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
for ( $keyi = (self::$form_options['time_format'] == '24') ? 0 : 1; $keyi <= $tf_hours; $keyi++ )
```

to

```
for ( $keyi = (self::$form_options['time_format'] == '24') ? 8 : 9; $keyi <= $tf_hours; $keyi++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think from you current output that `self::$form_options['time_format']` is set to 24. 
The syntax of for loop is

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement
```

here `expr1` is executed `once` at the start of the loop, and if `expr2` is evaluated to `TRUE` the the statement is executed, `expr3` is evaluated at the `end` of each iteration.

Now see the below code:

```
$tf_hours = (self::$form_options['time_format'] == '24') ? '17' : '12';
```

What the above code does is if time format is 24 then set `$tf_hours` with 17 , if not then with 12.

```
for ( $keyi = (self::$form_options['time_format'] == '24') ? 0 : 1; $keyi <= $tf_hours; $keyi++ ) {
```

Now the above code sets `expr1 (i.e $keyi)` to 0 or 1 based on the time format, `expr2 ($keyi <= $tf_hours)` checks whether value of `$keyi` is less than or equal to the value set in `$tf_hours` and if TRUE then execute the code inside the loop, and at the end of each iteration `expr3 (ie $keyi++)` increments the value set in `$keyi` by one.

So the code in your for loop will start with zero or one base on the time format and loop `$tf_hours` times.

So if you wish to start with 08 then set the `expr1` to 8 in your code:

```
for ( $keyi = (self::$form_options['time_format'] == '24') ? 8 : 1; $keyi <= $tf_hours; $keyi++ ) {
```

Hope this is helpful to you.